# Pandas: How to automate creation of loop to make multiple contingency tables for different groups?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create contingency tables, but I know only how to do it separately.

I created a dataframe (`df`) with information about one `disease`, `age` and `delta` (the difference betwen predicted age and real age, where "0",'1','-1' are normal/over/under age)

`df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[50,0,0],[42,1,1],[25,0,0], [25,1,1],[42,-1,0],[25,0,0]]),columns=['age', 'delta', 'disease'])`

After that I want to create `df` with peolpe of 25 years old, for it I do:

`df25 = df.loc[df['age'] == 25]`

and after that I can create contingency table by:

`pd.crosstab(index=df25['disease'], columns=df25['delta'])`

Now table is ready, but my real `df` is so big with a lot of unique ages. I tried to create loop, but it was not successful. Could you help me to automate this process please? I need table for every age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of age groups by [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with dict comprehension, as follows:

```
age_dict = {k:v for k, v in df.groupby('age')}
```

Then, you can access the individual group of age e.g. 25, by:

```
age_dict[25]
```

This give the same result as you do by `df25 = df.loc[df['age'] == 25]`:

```
print(age_dict[25])

   age  delta  disease
2   25      0        0
3   25      1        1
5   25      0        0
```

You can get the list of all age groups by:

```
age_dict_keys = [*age_dict.keys()]
```

Result:

```
print(age_dict_keys)

[25, 42, 50]
```

To print the contengancy tables for all age groups, you can use:

```
for key in age_dict_keys:
    print('==========================================')
    print('key=', key, '\ncrosstab:\n', pd.crosstab(index=age_dict[key]['disease'], columns=age_dict[key]['delta']))
```

**Output:**

```
==========================================
key= 25 
crosstab:
 delta    0  1
disease      
0        2  0
1        0  1
==========================================
key= 42 
crosstab:
 delta    -1   1
disease        
0         1   0
1         0   1
==========================================
key= 50 
crosstab:
 delta    0
disease   
0        1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unique_ages = df['age'].unique()

for age in unique_ages:
    df_temp = df.loc[df['age'] == age]
    # ... do something... save each df like so: df_temp.to_csv('table_for_age_'+ str(age) + '.csv')
    # ... or just work with temp_df inside the loop...
```

Comment: Thank you, but the result is not contigency table

Comment: inside the loop continue with your code... ```temp_contigency_table = pd.crosstab(index=df_temp['disease'], columns=df_temp['delta'])```

Answer (score 0):

All contingency tables are in d

```
d=dict()
for age,values in df.groupby("age"):
    d.update({f"df{age}":pd.crosstab(index=values["disease"],columns=values["delta"])})
```